# Working of sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

There is a big string. I want to store different parts of this in different variables. But it seems that either my understanding is not clear or there is a bug. Please help.

**here is my section of code.**

```
char sample[] = "abc,batsman,2,28.0,1800";

char name[10] ,speciality[10];
float batavg;
int pos, runs,j;

j = sscanf(sample,"%s,%s,%d,%f,%d", name, speciality, pos, batavg, runs);

printf("%s,%s,%d,%f,%d", name, speciality, pos, batavg, runs);
printf("\n%d\n",j);
```

**Output**

Some garbage values with the value of j = 1 in the above case is shown.

How can I settle this?

Comment: First of all it should be `if (j == 5) printf("%s ...`.

Comment: Please don't change your submitted code in response to answers. It makes them look out of context and it wasn't what you asked.

Comment: Rolled back OP's edit.

Comment: I didn't understand why it should be if (j == 5) printf("%s ....). Please explain.

Comment: Try this: j=sscanf(sample,"%[^,],%[^,],%d,%f,%d",name,speciality,&pos,&batavg,&runs); You have to pass the pointers of the variables in which you want sscanf stores the values! %[^,] means get chars until "," is found!

Comment: @Sunil the `scanf` family returns the number of fields successfully converted. So that is a basic check that the function did what you intended.

Comment: @ Weather : Sorry sir but I didn't edit the question after seeing the answers. I realised missing of "&" before seeing the answers. I saw the answers after my edit as page was not refreshed till then. But i will keep this in mind from the next time.

Comment: Yes, but you try the line I sent you in the comment! It runs ... !!! The variables that represent numbers are not pointers! ... And if you want to scan the string till the comma you cannot use %s because %s stop scanning at the first space or \t, \n, \r, \0!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini cheeky! You edited out the `&` before the two `char` array args after my (now) deleted comment, and you duplicated the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, because it was wrong! I apologize... I know that, but writing on the fly I've inserted & everywhere!!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scanf()` family of functions require you to pass *pointers* to the locations where the scanned fields should be stored.  That just works when you're scanning into a `char` array (field descriptor `%s`) because the name of a `char` array is converted to a pointer automatically, but for other kinds of fields you need to use address-of operator (`&`).

Additionally, as iharob first observed, the `%s` descriptor expects fields to be delimited by whitespace.  You can get what you want via the `%[]` descriptor:

```
j=sscanf(sample,"%[^,],%[^,],%d,%f,%d",name,speciality,&pos,&batavg,&runs);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"%s"` specifier in *`scanf()` family of functions scans all the characters until a white space happens.

So the first `"%s"` is consuming the whole string, that's why `j == 1`, you must check the value of `j` before printing, since all the other parameters are uninitialized at the moment of printing.

You need a different format specifier, namely

```
sscanf("%[^,],%[^,],%d,%f,%d", name, speciality, &pos, &batavg, &runs);
```